linux vim set clipboard as system clipboard
I am on a window 10 terminal using ssh remoting my machine on aubuntu 24 os and with vim(VIM - Vi IMproved 9.1 (2024 Jan 02, compiled May 03 2024 02:45:42))
The clipboard feature is onfeatures
vim config have been set "clipboard = unnamed" .vimrc setting
Also, I have tried all the option on this linkHow to copy selected lines to clipboard in vim.
The missing part I could image is one possible idea:The X11 compatiable for Win. I have not checked the x11 environment while it does work on my mac

Have you tried doing :set mouse=a in Vim on the remote machine?
